# How to use concatenation when port mapping in VHDL code when using ModelSim

Tags: vhdl

I would like to concatenate in the port mapping but unfortunatly I get an error when I compile my code in ModelSim, I read that concatenation in the port mapping is not supported by the software.
I don't know how to do it then.
Here is my code (I just copied the "begin" part as the rest doesn't matter:

```
signal en_out : std_logic;
signal count : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal segments_out : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

begin
output_1 : clock_divider port map(enable,reset,clk,en_out);
output_2 : counter port map(enable,reset,clk,count);
output_3 : seven_segment_decoder port map('0'&count, segments_out);
**--I want to concatenate here to obtain a 4-bit std_logic_vector**
HEX0 <= segments_out;

end behavioral;
```

Thanks for your help

I get an error in ModelSim saying : Actual expression (infix expression) of formal "code" is not globally static.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Consider using -2008 wherein a non-static expression is concurrently assigned to an anonymous intermediary signal declared in the enclosing declarative region whose scope encloses the component instantiation statement (See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.6.3 Port clauses). For earlier revisions of the standard declare an intermediary signal assigned the expression and use that as the actual.

Answer (score -3):

Try `"0" & count` in the port map.

Comment: While lacking a [mcve] you appear to be ignoring the error message. Also note the OP uses the positional associated actual matching your expression already. IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.4 Static expressions tells us a signal value isn't static while 6.5.6.3 Port clauses informs us of the use of an implicitly declared signal as the actual assigned the value of the expression.